# String Boot REST security Error : type=Forbidden, status=403

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-rest

This project I have used Spring boot, security authentication, JPA and REST

This gives me 403 error, which is of role base error. I have tried for 2 days could not solve please help.

Here I am sharing code.

This is my Security config class have roles based /hello for all user and /admin/all and /admin/add for admin user.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encodePsw());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/secure/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/api/secure/**")
            .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePsw() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

This is my Controller class have 3 method which is or 3 role based /hello for all user and /admin/all and /admin/add for admin user.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/secure")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passEncp;

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello..";
}

//@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserByAdmin(@RequestBody User user) {
    user.setPassword(passEncp.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepo.save(user);
    return "Add User Successfully";
}

//@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/admin/all")
public String securedHello() {
    return "Secured Hello";
}
}
```

This is Role bean

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int roleId;
private String role;
}
```

This User Bean

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {
@Id
private int userId;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

UserRepository interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

CustomUserDetails class 
I think the problem in this part. I have save role like ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN also tried without ROLE_

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

private User user;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(""+role))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto -generated method stub
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user.getUsername();
}
```

Service class CustomUserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    CustomUserDetails userDetails = null;
    if(user!=null) {
        userDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
        userDetails.setUser(user);
    }else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with name "+username);
    }
    return userDetails;
}
}
```

I have another Controller class having different URL mapping which is running

Comment: Add a break point at the following line: `return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(""+role))`, check if your role name is equal to the one on `@PreAuthorize`

Comment: `new SimpleGrantedAuthority(""+role)` should be a String value equal to the one inside `hasAnyRole('')` on the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. You are converting a object to a String. You should get the name/value from the `Role` object and pass that in.

Comment: Thank you rentius. role.getRole() work for me. I spent like 15 hours for this. Thank You very much

Comment: One more thing, while I am testing with postman it is giving login page code as response body(use basic Auth for username and password). But working fine in browser.

Answer (score 0):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has a overloaded configure message that takes WebSecurity as argument which accepts ant matchers on requests to be ignored.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/hello");
}
```

You can ignore /hello based url as its for all users.

Answer (score 0):

**Actual:**

```
return user.getRoles().stream().map(role->new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+role)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Expected:**

```
return user.getRoles().stream().map(role->new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+role.getRole_name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.